# Hosting WP app on server which already has Symfony2 app

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, nginx

I wrote an app for my customer in Symfony2 and we went public with that. However, I am learning right now that he had a separate `Wordpress` app within previous server to manage some separate product.

Now, he asks that we transfer that WP app on a new server. Being all security in mind, I cannot feel but nervous about potential impact here. I am to have the following URL setup:

- www.myclientapp.com
- www.myclientapp.com/some-wp

What are my options here? I can think of some, but any suggestion would be helpful.

1. Buy separate shared hosting and put WP there. Then do redirection from our website.
2. My VPS server runs with `nginx` and `php-fpm`. Can I utilize separate pools which would run under different user. I would need to review access privileges to Symfony's files.

In any case I would allocate separate `mysql` user and database. Those wold be enforced by strict privileges which prohibit access to my primary database.

Can you guys think of anything else?

**My primary goal is:** If WP is vulnerable, let it be. Under no circumstances I would allow it to compromise my `Symfony2` app. I am primarily concerned about configuration files (`app/config/*.yml`) which contain sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend that you use something like a sub-domain eg wp.symfony.com.

They may still be hosted on the same server, but using different virtual host directories. 
With that, the apps will never see each other.

Comment: Hey Army, thanks for a prompt answer. Wouldn't some vulnerable plugin still have access to `/path/to/symfony2/app/config/*` files? If not, that is definitely a good solution - that is if my customer agrees to move `wp` to subdomain (marketing implications)

Comment: Since the directories are isolated from each other, There won't been any vulnerability due to the wp domain, as long as your symfony is normally secured as it will be in a normal host environment. you can use .htaccess to secure any directory as well.

Comment: Yes, but given that server is ran by a single user (`nginx` in my case), what stops a `wp` from reading my files? I am not talking about some one requesting a config file via URL, but a malicious (or compromised) plugin reading it (and exposing my db access info). Example would be simple: `file_gets_content('/..../config.yml')`.

Comment: Yeah, WP might not be able to directly access your Symfony App, but if it accesses your server somehow, then Symfony can be compromised, So if you are not sure, you can ask your client about using a different server, so as not to take the blame for WP security flaws. You can still achieve your desired url configuration.

Answer (score 1):

A way is running symfony under a different php-fpm user than the WP website and make sure the file/directory rights are set correctly. Then a WP exploit cannot write/read to the symfony files depending on the directory/file rights.

A better way is to use the php config open_basedir and isolate the two sites into their own "jails" this way PHP prevents including/reading files from other websites. See http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir for more information.

For this to work the code should be separated into different directories, you can use nginx aliases or virtualhosts to point the domainname to the correct directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, `open_basedir` can be circumvented quite easily :-/ (link: http://serverfault.com/questions/431200/how-to-add-an-open-basedir-path-in-nginx-vhost). But running as a different user should definitely be a direction in which I'd like to move :)

Comment: Thanks, did not know that. So you should also disable the shell_exec and system functions to be more safe.